# Equality in distribution of two processes given by similar SDEs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W_t$ be a univariate standard Brownian motion. Let $\vec{B}_t$ be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\vec{S}_t$ be a vector valued process in $(0,\infty)^d$, driven by $\vec{B}_t$ with a rather general geometric Brownian motion dynamics: for each $i=1,2,\dotsc,d$, the coordinate $S_t^i$ satisfies the SDE
$$dS_t^i=\mu^i(t,\vec{S}_.)S_t^i dt+\sum_{j=1}^m \sigma_{ij}(t,\vec{S}_.)S_t^i dB_t^j.$$

Here the notation $\sigma_{ij}(t, \vec{S}_.)$ means that $\sigma_{ij}$ is a function of time $t$ and *the entire path* of $\vec{S}$ up to time $t$, and hence so is the $d\times m$ matrix $\sigma(t, \vec{S}_.)$. Note that $\Sigma=\sigma \sigma^T$ is thus $d\times d$ and represents the covariance matrix of the system $\log\vec{S}$ (the logarithm applied component wise, I apologize for these slight abuses of notation). Similar comments apply to $\mu^i(t, \vec{S}_t)$ and $\vec{\mu}(t, \vec{S}_t)$.

Consider two processes  $X_t^{(1)}$ and $X_t^{(2)}$ defined by the SDEs
$$dX_t^{(1)} = \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_t^i \sigma_{ij}(t,\vec{S}_.)X_t^{(1)} dB_t^j,$$
and
$$dX_t^{(2)} = \sqrt{\vec{\alpha}_t^T \Sigma(t, \vec{S}_.) \vec{\alpha}_t} X_t^{(2)}dW_t,$$
where $\Sigma=\sigma\sigma^T$.

**Conjecture:**
If $X_0^{(1)}=X_0^{(2)}$ a.s., then for all $t>0$,
$$X_t^{(1)} \stackrel{(d)}{=} X_t^{(2)},$$
i.e. these are equal in distribution at every time $t>0$.

**Special case:**
I believe we can prove this when $\sigma_{ij}$ are functions of time $t$ alone. Indeed, it is easy to see the quadratic variations are extremely similar:
$$d[X]_t^{(i)} = \vec{\alpha}_t^T \Sigma(t) \vec{\alpha}_t (X_t^{(i)})^2 dt.$$
Applying Ito's lemma to $\log X_t^{(i)}$ shows that the both $\log X_t^{(i)}$ are Gaussian with mean
$$-\frac12 \int_0^t \vec{\alpha}_u^T \Sigma(u)\vec{\alpha}_u du,$$
and variance
$$\int_0^t \vec{\alpha}_u^T \Sigma(u)\vec{\alpha}_u du.$$
Thus, the two are equal in distribution at each time.

**Question**
Is this conjecture true in general? How can we proceed to prove it?

Please comment for clarifications or corrections, especially for my little sketch of a proof of the special case, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with $\sigma$ constant to the identity?

Comment: @blamethelag I am not sure what you mean by "$\sigma$ constant to the identity", sorry. I have tried $\sigma$ as a function of time $t$ (which includes a constant matrix), and it seems to work, as I have sketched above in the special case of the OP.

Comment: @NapD.Lover 3 questions: 1/ we must have $d =m$ (because $\Sigma=\sigma\sigma^T$), right? 2/ what do you mean by "$\vec{S}_t$ be a vector driven by $\vec{B}_t$"? and 3/ I think the red term is missing and need to be added $$dX_t^{(1)} = \sum_{i=1}^d \sum_{j=1}^d \alpha_t^i \sigma_{ij}(t,\vec{S}_.) \color{red}{\alpha_t^j} X_t^{(1)} dB_t^j$$

Comment: @NN2 If I am not mistaken: 1/ No, that is not necessary. In the simplest case of $d=1$ asset, the prices might be driven by $m=2$ noises (one from volatility and one from volatility-independent price-mechanisms; see the Heston model). 2/ I mean each coordinate satisfies a very general geometric Brownian motion SDE $$dS_t^i=\mu^i(t,\vec{S}_.)S_t^i dt+\sum_{j=1}^m \sigma_{ij}(t,\vec{S}_.)S_t^i dB_t^j,$$ for $i=1,2,\dotsc,d$ I apologize, that phrase was indeed a bit vague...(continued in next comment)

Comment: @NN2 3/ Here $dX^{(1)}$ is the stochastic differential of a portfolio of assets $\vec{S}$ and weights $\vec{\alpha}$ *ignoring drifts*:  if you compute $$dX^{(1)}=\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\alpha^iX_t^{(1)}}{S_t^i} dS_t^i,$$ using the SDE I just wrote for $S_t^i$, simplify and group terms, and then drop all of the drift terms (those in front of the "$dt$" only), then you get $\sum_{i=1}^d\sum_{j=1}^m \alpha_t^i \sigma_{ij}(t, \vec{S}_.)X_t^{(1)} dB_t^{j}$ so the red term does not arise from the setting of the model--but it may certainly be studied elsewhere.... I can definitely add this to the OP.

Comment: @NN2 (I am ignoring drifts here because if you include them and take the difference $X^{(1)}-X^{(2)}$ the drift vanishes, so it is not relevant for my specific question here--obviously we need to include them in actual financial modeling...)

Comment: @NapD.Lover For 1/ I agree that we can have $d\ne m$ mathematically. But in quantitative finance, usually $d=m$, otherwise the market is not complete or may have arbitrage. In Heston model, there is a second process: the volatility one

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture holds true only in the case where $\sigma_{ij}$ depends only on $t$ as in your special case.

We build a counter-example for the case where $\sigma_{ij}$ is a function of $t$ and $S$.

For the sake of notation clarity, I write the indices in subscript, for example $S_{2,t}$  (and not in superscript as in your question $S^{2}_t$).

Let us suppose

- $(d,m)=(2,2)$
- $(\sigma_{1,1},\sigma_{1,2},\sigma_{2,1},\sigma_{2,2})=(B_{2,t},0,0, B_{1,t})$
- $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = (1,1)$

Then

- The dynamic of $\vec{S}_t$:
  $$\begin{align}
  \frac{dS_{1,t}}{S_{1,t}}&=B_{2,t}\cdot dB_{1,t}\\
  \frac{dS_{2,t}}{S_{2,t}}&=B_{1,t}\cdot dB_{2,t}\\
  \end{align}$$
- The dynamic of $X^{(1)}_t$:
  $$\begin{align}
  \frac{dX^{(1)}_t}{X^{(1)}_t}&=\alpha_1\frac{dS_{1,t}}{S_{1,t}} + \alpha_2\frac{dS_{2,t}}{S_{2,t}}\\
  &=1\cdot B_{2,t}\cdot dB_{1,t}+1\cdot B_{1,t}\cdot dB_{2,t}\\
  &=d(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}) \tag{1}\\
  \end{align}$$
- The dynamic of $X^{(2)}_t$:
  $$\frac{dX^{(2)}_t}{X^{(2)}_t}= \sqrt{(B_{1,t} + B_{2,t})^2} dW_t = \left|B_{1,t} + B_{2,t} \right|dW_t \tag{2}$$

It's easy to deduce the analytical solution of $X^{(1)}_t$ and $X^{(2)}_t$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$:
$$\begin{align}
(1) &\Longrightarrow d{\ln\left(X^{(1)}_t \right)} = -\frac{1}{2}\left(B_{1,t}^2+B_{2,t}^2  \right)dt+d(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}) \\
&\Longrightarrow \color{red}{X^{(1)}_t = X^{(1)}_0\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\left(B_{1,s}^2+B_{2,s}^2  \right)ds+B_{1,t}B_{2,t} \right)} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
(2) &\Longrightarrow d{\ln\left(X^{(2)}_t \right)} = -\frac{1}{2}(B_{1,t}+B_{2,t})^2  dt+\left|B_{1,t} + B_{2,t} \right|dW_t \\
&\Longrightarrow \color{blue}{X^{(2)}_t = X^{(2)}_0\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(B_{1,s}+B_{2,s})^2ds+ \int_0^t \left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|dW_s \right)} \tag{4}
\end{align}$$

Even if we suppose $X^{(1)}_0 = X^{(2)}_0 $, we can not have $X^{(1)}_t \stackrel{(d)}{=}X^{(2)}_t$. Indeed, let's study the two exponents

$$\begin{align}
\text{Exponent}(3)-\text{Exponent}(4)
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\left(B_{1,s}^2+B_{2,s}^2  \right)ds+B_{1,t}B_{2,t}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t(B_{1,s}+B_{2,s})^2ds- \int_0^t \left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|dW_s\\
&=\color{red}{\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds+B_{1,t}B_{2,t}}- \color{blue}{ \int_0^t \left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|dW_s}  \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
If $X^{(1)}_t \stackrel{(d)}{=}X^{(2)}_t$, the red term of $(5)$ must equal to the blue term in law. Their variances must be then equal. However,

By Ito isometric, the variance of the blue term of $(5)$ is equal to
$$\begin{align}
V\left(\int_0^t \left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|dW_s  \right) &= \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\int_0^t \left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|dW_s \right)^2  \right) \\
&= \int_0^t \mathbb{E}\left|B_{1,s} + B_{2,s} \right|^2ds   \\
&= \int_0^t 2sds   \\
&= t^2  \\
\end{align}$$

The variance of the red term:
$$\begin{align}
L&:= V\left(\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds+B_{1,t}B_{2,t}  \right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds+B_{1,t}B_{2,t}  \right)^2 \\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds\right)^2  +2\mathbb{E}\left(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds  \right)
+\mathbb{E}\left(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}  \right)^2  \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
We can compute $(6)$ analytically but it is time consuming for me. Just observe that, as $B_{1,t}$ and $B_{2,t}$ are independent, then

- The third term of $(6)$ is equal to $t^2$
- The first term is positive
- The second term is also positive because
  $$\mathbb{E}\left(B_{1,t}B_{2,t}\int_0^t(B_{1,s}B_{2,s})ds  \right) = \int_0^t\mathbb{E}(B_{1,t}B_{1,s}B_{2,t}B_{2,s})ds = \int_0^t\mathbb{E}(B_{1,t}B_{1,s})\mathbb{E}(B_{2,t}B_{2,s})ds =\int_0^t (\max{t,s} \cdot \max{t,s})  > 0$$
  So, the variance of $(6)$ is greater than $t^2$ or greater than the variance of the blue term.

Q.E.D

Comment: Hello @NN2. How does this prove that we don't have equality in distribution?

Comment: @Snoop I thought it’s evident. It suffices to compare the 2 exponent terms.

Comment: I’ll complete the answer later.

Comment: @Snoop It's done. Tell me whether it's clear.

Comment: ok I'll have a look later on

Comment: Ok, I'm getting the idea, but I have a question. Let's just suppose $X^1_0=X^2_0=1$. If $X^1_t\sim X^2_t$, then $\ln(X_t^1)\sim \ln(X_t^2)$. At this point we may compare the variances of $\ln(X_t^1)$ and $\ln(X_t^2)$ and reach a contradiction if there is. But why study $\ln(X_t^1)-\ln(X_t^2)=Y-Z$ to reach the conclusion? I mean, how we would claim that $X_t^1\sim X_t^2\implies Z\sim Y$? Sorry for being pedantic.

Comment: @Snoop Compare $\ln(X^{(1)}_t)$ and $\ln(X^{(2)}_t)$ is exactly the same as compare the exponent of $X^{(1)}_t$ and $X^{(2)}_t$, yes perhaps we economize 1-2 lines of argument.

Comment: @Snoop  For the second point, I do that as a trick to compute easily the variance. I agree that a better solution should be to compute the variance of $\ln(X^{(1)}_t)$ and $\ln(X^{(2)}_t)$ directly (it's completely doable but very time consuming).

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for the answer. I will review it in detail in the next week and probably accept this. But in the meantime, and perhaps this should be a new question, but what can we say if we require $\vec{\alpha}$ to satisfy $\vec{1}^T \vec{\alpha}=1$ and $\vec{\alpha}\succeq 0$? This counterexample would no longer be applicable, but perhaps we can still find another one... (sincere apologies for not including these constraints in the OP).

Comment: @NapD.Lover Changing $\vec{\alpha}$ does not change the conclusion. For example $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right)$ satisfies your 2 conditions. The variance of the blue term of $(5)$ will equal to $\frac{t^2}{2}$ while the variance of the third term of $(6)$ is also equal to $\frac{t^2}{2}$. As the variances of first and second term of $(6)$ are positive, we have the same conclusion.

Comment: $(1,1)^T(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})=1/\sqrt{2}+1/\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}\neq 1$ but I see your point that the counterexample is robust to these conditions with suitable modifications. I was a bit in a rush when I asked so thank you for the easy clarification.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Ah, sorry, I mean $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2) = \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$ and the corresponding variances in my comment above is $\frac{t^2}{4}$. And you're welcome!